# Running applescript with timer

Tags: macos, applescript

I am trying to run an applescript. The content of the script is not important but I would like to run it at timed intervals until a certain condition is met. For example, I want to click on a menu item in Safari browser if it's available:

The applescript that I want to run:

```
on menuClick()
  tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Safari"
      click menu item "Simulator" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Develop" of menu bar 1
    end tell
  end tell
end menuClick
```

The pseudocode of how I would like the script to run (Sorry, my knowledge of applescript is limited):

```
try
  menuClick()
catch
  run menuClick after 1s
```

How would the pseudocode look like in Applescript?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to run applescript periodically, use "Idle" handler :

```
On idle
-- do this and this / add you code
return xxx
end idle
```

you run your code and it will keep running for ever (except if your code contains a quit command). the xxx value after the return is the number of seconds (positive !) before the next run. in your code, you can check application current status, or any other things.
If not enough, you can use launchd method (se Apple launchd).

Comment: That didn't work. But I played with "try, on error, end try" block and that seemed to work. Except that I need to somehow avoid stack overflow (not this site :P) when I try to call `menuClick` again in `on error`